# Android camera flipped

Tags: java, android, camera

I have followed [this](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/blob/master/Camera/Preview/src/com/commonsware/android/camera/PreviewDemo.java) example. However, when I port it to my phone (in order to use the camera), the preview is flipped 90 degrees to the left. Other than that it is working fine.

My question is then: **how do I "unflip" the preview**?

Here is the content of my layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">   
        <android.view.SurfaceView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/preview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </android.view.SurfaceView> 
</LinearLayout>
```

Also, when I try to turn the phone myself it stays in 'landscape' mode.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you say "flipped 90 degrees to the left" do you mean it ends up in portrait or landscape?

Comment: When you say 'flipped' do you mean 'rotated'? If so maybe it seems too obvious but you do have horizontal in your orientation. Or maybe I misunderstand the question!

Comment: Yes, it ends up in landscape. And it doesn't matter whether or not orientation is 'horizontal' or 'vertical', still the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue before.  I just added a parameter to rotate the view 90.  Add this parameter to the surface changed function:

```
parameters.setRotation(90);
```